# How to create protected page in react nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i am fairly new to nextjs. I am trying to create protected page for authorised users on my web app.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to structure it? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-cookie-auth

Comment: you definitely need a HOC component to and wrap your page with it. ad Alessio mentioned the documentation is covering what u want!

Answer (score 2):

To answer you question, it depends.
You can do it two ways:

### Front end protection

When the page loads, show some kind of loading state. For example spinner.
Meanwhile, checks if user is logged and if not, use next/router to redirect user to Login page (for example).

### Server protection

For server protection, you can use `getServerSideProps` function. It can look something like this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  // fetch user logged state
  // check if user is logged
  // you can use server side redirection or pass "redirect" prop to 
  // the component and redirect on page load
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```